# BeautifulSoup tried to find by text but returned nothing?

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The program was intended to search through a table on the web.

```
single_paper_soup.find('dl').find_all("dt")
```

returns:

```
[<dt>Volume:</dt>,
 <dt>Month:</dt>,
 <dt>Year:</dt>,
 <dt>Venues:</dt>,
 <dt>Pages:</dt>,
 <dt>Language:</dt>,
 <dt>URL:</dt>,
 <dt>DOI:</dt>,]
```

However, when I dived into the content by searching text:

```
single_paper_soup.find('dl').find_all("dt",string = "Year")
```

it returned nothing:

```
[]
```

Both `string` and `text` methods returned nothing.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-string

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a string per `string` or `text` needs exact string to match in your case:

```
soup.find_all("dt",string = "Year:")
```

There are other options to search for a tag that conatins a string / substring,

Use `css selectors` and `:-soup-contains()`:

```
soup.select('dt:-soup-contains("Year")')
```

Import `re` and use `re.compile()` to find your tag with text:

```
soup.find_all("dt", text=re.compile("Year"))
```

#### Example

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<dt>Volume:</dt>
 <dt>Month:</dt>
 <dt>Year:</dt>
 <dt>Venues:</dt>
 <dt>Pages:</dt>
 <dt>Language:</dt>
 <dt>URL:</dt>
 <dt>DOI:</dt>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('dt:-soup-contains("Year")')
soup.find_all("dt",string = "Year:")
soup.find_all("dt", text=re.compile("Year"))
```